# How long should we set the HTTP Expires or Cache-control: max-age header?

Tags: caching, http-headers, browser-cache, web-performance, expires-header

Let's say if the `bundle.js` is 750kb, is it true that if you set it to "never expire" or "expire in 10 years", then the browser doesn't need to fetch that file and therefore can make your website and pageload faster?

(By the way, it is said that `Cache-control: max-age` is HTTP/1.1 and [if it and `Expires:` are both present, `Cache-control` overrides the `Expires` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires).)

What if you have a weekly or 2-month release cycle, should you set the Expires header to 1 week or 2 months? I was thinking that with a weekly release cycle, some of your JavaScript or CSS files may stay the same, so it may be good to just set it to expire in 6 months or even 10 years? (because one week later it hasn't changed?)

But what if your file changed but the browser doesn't fetch it?  Is it true that if you use the ETag mechanism, or if you use `bundle.53ae823.js` or `bundle.2020-03-12-08.js`, then you can "force" it to expire by the ETag being different, or the file name being different?  What is a good way to set the Expires header length?

Answer (score 0):

You could use all of those techniques at the same time. If you can include a hash in your filenames and the references to them ([example of how to do it in webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/)), then you can be sure that you can bust the cache whenever you change something.

Then you could set `Cache-control: max-age` to 31536000 (a year, the max) because you can trust the file with URI to not change (because of the hash, if the file changes ,the URI will too).

And of course you can implement ETAG in order to enable revalidation of the cache. This will still require a request to be sent to your server/CDN, but will save the user having to download the whole file if it hasn't changed.

There is a nice article on this topic, [here](https://jakearchibald.com/2016/caching-best-practices/).